# Как поставить время обращения к серверу (code first entity framework, mvvm wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Создал модель (Code fluent):

```
    public PersonConfig()
    {
        HasKey(id => id.PersonID);
        Property(name => name.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class CodeContext: DbContext
    {
        public CodeContext(string connectionString) : base( connectionString)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Person{ get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfig());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

После, во viewmodel отправляю строку, делаю инициализацию:

```
    try
    {
        using (var cnxt = new CodeContext(connectionString))
        {
             cnxt.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка с сервером");
   }
```

Проблема такая: если обращаюсь на сервер, который есть, то все отлично, после с ним работаю (если бд нет, создает, если есть, то использует ее). 
Но если строка сервера неверна, то загрузка идет около 01:07 минут, и только после перемещается в catch(exception ex). Как время обращения к серверу уменьшить?? Или как проверить, корректно ли сервер ввели. Со временем я пытался в CodeContext писать, чтобы 30 секунд, но не работает.:

```
this.Database.CommandTimeout = 30;
```

Как решить эту проблему? Мб я неверно делаю инициализацию, хотя по-другому не получается, да и если строка сервера верна, то обращение идет без проблем (но обращение к корректному серверу, изначально, около 8 секунд, что, как кажется, будет много, ведь обращаюсь к себе)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете *таймаут команды*, который определяет таймаут выполнения запроса (который будет справедлив после установления соединения с БД). В вашем случае, вам нужен *таймаут подключения*, который говорит о времени ожидании подключения к базе данных, а точнее, через какое время это ожидание будет прервано и будет сгенерирована ошибка.

> The length of time (in seconds) to wait for a connection to the server
>   before terminating the attempt and generating an error.

можете указать его прямо в [строке подключения](https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/) к базе данных

```
Connection Timeout=60;
```

---

> Но, это так, если я обращаюсь к несуществующему серверу, если сервер
>   есть (я пробовал обратиться к себе от прав не администратора, к
>   администратору, к чему доступа как раз нет), и время обращения было 6
>   секунд! Каков алгоритм времени? Как он выбирает, как и быть теперь?

Параметр `Connection Timeout` определяет как [долго служба SQL будет отвечать на попытку соединения](http://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts/). Другими словами, эту попытку сперва нужно предпринять, достучавшись до сервера SQL. Этот параметр не регулирует время сетевых задержек, проблем с DNS или другие проблемы.

Comment: Я добавил в строку что Вы сказали: `"Data Source=tempServer;Initial Catalog = database;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Application Name=EntityFramework"`, - но теперь загрузка как будто вечна. Идет обращение к серверу (исходя из исключения) после `OnModelCreating`, и ошибка такая выводится (что мб и должно быть при некорректном вводе сервера): `(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Не удалось открыть подключение к SQL Server)` . Но я хотел бы это через секунд 30, а не через минуты 2 ?

Comment: Странное поведение. Попробуйте так же добавить в конструктор `CodeContext` тайм-аут команды `((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 35;`

Comment: @Bruceee, вам помогло? Если нет, то мне придется удалить ответ, как бесполезный.

Comment: То, что вы предложили выше (с `objectcontext`) также, однако, я провел эксперимент, в значение `connect timeout` ставил значения от 1 до 8 и каждый раз измерял время обращения к серверу, и заметил интересную закономерность (но меня она удивила, почему так??):
`1 - 10 секунд; 
2 - 10 секунд; 
3 - 20 секунд; 
4 - 20  секунд; 
5 - 30 секунд; 
6 - 30 секунд; 
7 - 40 секунд; 
8 - 40 секунд; `
....
`(2*n - 1; 2*n) = 10*n секунд`; 
 Измерял я после самого первого обращения `OnModelCreating`. Вы не знаете случайно, почему так?

Comment: Но, это так, если я обращаюсь к несуществующему серверу, если сервер есть (я пробовал обратиться к себе от прав не администратора, к администратору, к чему доступа как раз нет), и время обращения было 6 секунд! Каков алгоритм времени? Как он выбирает, как и быть теперь?

Comment: > Каков алгоритм времени?. Дополнил ответ

Comment: То есть получается, что если сервер есть, то мои значения `connect timeout = 6` будет проходить около 6 секунд (если соединиться), а если сервера нет, то неизвестно когда будет исключение? И отсюда следует, что никак нельзя явно указать время обращения к существующему/ не существующему серверу? Кстати, при последующем запросе на сервер, время, если сервер не существует, уменьшается в два раза, а если существует, туда же обращаться, то моментально, сразу же

Comment: Логично. Если вы не можете авторизоваться, то нет причин ждать 30 секунд. Время ожидания было бы справедливо, если сервер, например, был загружен. Определить сетевую доступность узла можно другими инструментами, но, вероятно, не тайм-аутом.